# Adding arrows, text, and overlaying to two nodes pointing to the same node in beamer and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows, nodes

I would like to create a diagram similar to:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/marketing-distribution-channel/

Instead, I would like for the 2 nodes at the bottom to point to the top node, and I cannot get them to do so unless they overlap.

Also, I'd like to add text just as in the link, like the test Participation Rate in that link that is just aside the arrows.  However, every time that I add text, the nodes shift so far to the right that some are no longer on the screen.

The other thing that I would like to do is after I've shown all of the nodes, I'd like to put up a new frametitle.  I was thinking only or uncover may do the trick but it does not seem to.  I'd also like to add some text with bullets.  Yet, it does not seem to follow the same spacing and font.  See overlay 5 versus Slide 2.

I would be grateful for any help.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>
 \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \useoutertheme{miniframes}
  \usepackage{color}

  \usepackage{tikz}
       \ussetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc,matrix,decorations.text,shapes.geometric}


 \begin{document}

 \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
 \tikzstyle{labels} = [font=\footnotesize, text centered,red]
  \tikzstyle{pointer} = [->,red, thick, >=latex']
  \tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  }}

  \frame
  {
  \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]  

   \tikzset{
    mynode/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=white, bottom          color=yellow!50,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=2em, text centered},
myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, very thick},
  mylabel/.style={text width=10em, text centered} 
 } 
     \uncover<1-4>{\node[mynode, align=center,draw,onslide=<1-3>] at (0,0) (a) {Line 1\\Line 2};}
     \uncover<1-3>{\node[mynode, align=center,draw,onslide=<1-3>] at (4.75,0) (b) {Line 1\\Line 2};}
     \uncover<1-3>{\draw[myarrow] (a) -- (b);}
     \uncover<2-3>{\node[mynode, align=center,draw,onslide=<2-3>] at (-2,-3.75) (c) {Line 1:\\Line 2};
    \uncover<2-3>{\node[below=-1.35cm of c] (dummy) {};}
    \uncover<3-3>{\node[right=-0.35cm of c] (dummy2) {};}
    \uncover<2-3>{\node[mylabel, below = of dummy](label1){\hspace{0.10cm}\hyperlink{eac<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}};}
    \uncover<2-3>{\draw[myarrow] (c.north) -- +(0,0) -- ++(0,1) -| (a.south);}}
   \uncover<3-4>{\node[mynode, align=center,draw,onslide=<3-3>] at (2,-3.75) (d) {Line 1\\Line 2};
   \uncover<3-4>{\node[right=-0.35cm of d] (dummy3) {};}
   \uncover<3-4>{\draw[myarrow] (d.north)  -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,1) -| (a.south);}}

  \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{figure}
  \uncover<6-6>{Test}
 }
\end{document}
```

EDIT: using the code in the answer, there still seems to be a problem with long text in one of the nodes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc,matrix,decorations.text,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

 \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{labels} = [font=\footnotesize, text centered,red]
\tikzstyle{pointer} = [->,red, thick, >=latex']
\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
 \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\begin{frame}
 \only<1-4>{\frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}}
 \only<5->{\frametitle{Some Other Title}}

\only<5->{
 \textbf{Sample:}
 \begin{itemize}
\item Peace
 \item Love
  \item War
 \end{itemize}

 \vspace{0.65cm}
 \textbf{Sample2:}
 }      

 \begin{figure}
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]  

\tikzset{
mynode/.style=
{rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=white, 
bottom color=yellow!50,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=2em, align=center},
myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, very thick},
mylabel/.style={text width=10em, text centered} 
} 

\uncover<1-4>{\node[mynode] at (0,0) (a) {Line 1\\Line 2};}
\uncover<1-3>{\node[mynode] at (4.75,0) (b) {Line 1\\Line 2};}
\uncover<1-3>{\draw[myarrow] (a) -- (b);}
 \uncover<2-3>{\node[mynode] at (-2,-3.75) (c) {Line 1:\\Line 2};
 \uncover<2-3>{\node[below=-1.35cm of c] (dummy) {};}
\uncover<3-3>{\node[right=-0.35cm of c] (dummy2) {};}
 \uncover<2-3>{\node[mylabel, below = of dummy] (label1)
{\hspace{0.10cm}\hyperlink{eac<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}};}
\uncover<2-3>{\draw[myarrow] (c.north) -- +(0,0) -- ++(0,1) 
 node[swap,anchor=west,text width=3cm] {some really really really long text goes here} -| (a.250);}}
 \uncover<3-4>{\node[mynode] at (2,-3.75) (d) {Line 1\\Line 2};
 \uncover<3-4>{\node[right=-0.35cm of d] (dummy3) {};}
 \uncover<3-4>{\draw[myarrow] (d.north)  -- ++(0,0) --  ++(0,1) 
 node[swap,anchor=west,text width=3cm] {some really really really long text goes here} -| (a.290);}}

 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some Other Title}
\textbf{Sample:}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Peace
\item Love
\item War
 \end{itemize}

\vspace{0.65cm}
\textbf{Sample2:}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you need?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc,matrix,decorations.text,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

 \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{labels} = [font=\footnotesize, text centered,red]
\tikzstyle{pointer} = [->,red, thick, >=latex']
\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
 \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\begin{frame}
 \only<1-4>{\frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}}
 \only<5->{\frametitle{Some Other Title}}

\only<5->{
 \textbf{Sample:}
 \begin{itemize}
\item Peace
 \item Love
  \item War
 \end{itemize}

 \vspace{0.65cm}
 \textbf{Sample2:}
 }      

\only<1-4>{%
\begin{figure}
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]  

\tikzset{
mynode/.style=
{rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=white, 
bottom color=yellow!50,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=2em, align=center},
myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, very thick},
mylabel/.style={text width=10em, text centered} 
} 

\uncover<1-4>{\node[mynode] at (0,0) (a) {Line 1\\Line 2};}
\uncover<1-3>{\node[mynode] at (4.75,0) (b) {Line 1\\Line 2};}
\uncover<1-3>{\draw[myarrow] (a) -- (b);}
 \uncover<2-3>{\node[mynode] at (-2,-3.75) (c) {Line 1:\\Line 2};
 \uncover<2-3>{\node[below=-1.35cm of c] (dummy) {};}
\uncover<3-3>{\node[right=-0.35cm of c] (dummy2) {};}
 \uncover<2-3>{\node[mylabel, below = of dummy] (label1)
{\hspace{0.10cm}\hyperlink{eac<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}};}
\uncover<2-3>{\draw[myarrow] (c.north) -- +(0,0) -- ++(0,1) 
 node[swap,anchor=east,text width=3cm] {some really really really long text goes here} -| (a.250);}}
 \uncover<3-4>{\node[mynode] at (2,-3.75) (d) {Line 1\\Line 2};
 \uncover<3-4>{\node[right=-0.35cm of d] (dummy3) {};}
 \uncover<3-4>{\draw[myarrow] (d.north)  -- ++(0,0) --  ++(0,1) 
 node[swap,anchor=west,text width=3cm] {some really really really long text goes here} -| (a.290);}}

 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  It is very helpful.  If I add too much text in the "Text goes here" part, it pushes all of the nodes to the right.  Do I adjust that with the text width?  Also, is there a way to use the equivalent of \\ with that?  I get syntax errors when I try \\.

Comment: @JG yes, you can use `text width` as option to the node to control the width; using this option, you can use \\ to explicitly break lines.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: To be able to add explicit line breaks, it's sufficient to specify an `align` option, you don't have to fix the `text width`.

Comment: @Jake you're right. I mentioned the `text width` option since it allows to fix the width and automatically produce break lines.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yeah, sorry, the comment was more directed at J G, in case he also wanted an option to produce manual line breaks without hardcoding the text width.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina.  Thank you for adding the new code!  However, when I try implementing it (I put it for the left side arrow), the text ends up running on top of the arrow rather than to its left.

Comment: @JG please edit your question and add the code you are using; otherwise, it's very difficult to provide precise advise.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Added.

Comment: @JG If it's OK with you I'll edit your question to recover the original code; the original question and the new code are not completely related, so I think it's best to leave the original code and simply add the new one in an edit.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, edit as you would like.

Comment: @JG I hope the edit is OK; I updated my answer with a solution for the problem mentioned.

Comment: @Jake.  With align, you can manually set the break akin to \\ for each line?  How would that work?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It looks great!  See my comment above to Jake for a follow up.

Comment: @JG all you need to do is to use `align=center`, `align=right` or `align=left` and then you can manually break lines using \\.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you!  That works really well!  May I please ask a follow up?  Currently I have the two nodes (c and d) pointing to box a.  What if I only have node c?  Would it be possible to put that really long text on the right of the arrow?  With anchor=east, it goes on the left, but with anchor=west, it starts on the arrow on the right side.  I am wondering how to insert a little more space so that it does not start on the arrow but rather off of the arrow on the west side.

Comment: @JG You can use `xshift=<length>` to horizontally shift a node; for example, `xshift=20pt` will move the node `20pt` to the right, and `xshift=-10pt` will move it `10pt` to the left.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina In the 6th overlay, I would like to add a standard set of text with bullets.  A \begin{itemize} \end{itemize}.  However, the spacing and font size look completely different.  I had some success using \only<6>{} before the begin{figure}.  However, the resulting text still looks to be a bit off compared to how it looks on other slides.  Does something happen to just regular text because of the figure?

Comment: @JG Hmmm... again, without the code, it's really difficult to see where the problem could be. I did some tests and everything looked OK. I need to see the code; edit your question and instead of the code that appears on the edit add the new problematic code with a little note explaining the new problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've edited the second one to add the code.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Do you see what I mean in the second example?  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @JG Yes; I saw it, but was busy. I've updated my answer with a solution to the new issue; the problem was that the `figure` environment had no overlay specification, so it ended "pushing up" the items and reducing their vertical spacing; adding some overlay specification, as in my updated answer solves the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you so much!  My apologies for the impatience.  I just thought that I might not have been explaining it clearly.  But this helps tremendously.  I'm going to play around with the code for a little bit.  Thank you!!

Comment: @JG No problem. You're welcome! Don't forget, if you consider so after some time, to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina This is incredibly minor.  But, I've noticed suddenly that the yellow!50 does not come across in the .pdf.  It looks white.  I use TeXWorks that has some sort of .pdf viewer, and in that the yellow works.  It is only in the .pdf that it does not.  Just noticed that.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JG and what viewer (the one exhibiting the problem) are you using to view the final .pdf? The problem appears if you process the exact document in my answer or only with your actual code?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am using a version of Adobe Acrobat to view the code.  I get the problem when viewing either version of the code.  In Acrobat, it comes across yellow if I do yellow, but white if I do yellow!50, but in TeXWorks, it looks fine.

Comment: @JG Sorry, but no idea what is happening; I made some tests using Acrobat Reader, Evince and Okular and everything worked as expected. This is not a LaTeX/TeX issue, but seems like a viewer-related problem. Try with another viewer.